# How to report/fix Spring framework documentation issues

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I found few typos/mistakes in [Spring Boot reference guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-metrics.html).
Could you please suggest whom can I contact, or even better how to fix it myself (e.g via pull request if possible) ?
I checked spring GitHub repository but [spring-boot-actuator-docs](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-actuator-docs) seems to have nothing to do with reference guide.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring Boot is like any regular github project. It is located here:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot

If you want to fix the typos, create a pull request. You'll find all you need to know in our [contributing page](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.adoc). The documentation is located in the [spring-boot-docs module](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-docs/src/main/asciidoc)

Comment: Hello Stephane, thanks for pointing me to correct repository !